# Flutter User reporting

Tags: flutter, dart

I want users who share bad content in my Flutter application to report each other, but I don't know how. Is there anyone who can help me on this issue? What path should I follow?

Comment: You will need some kind of backend to store the reports and user ids, than you can check if the user is disabled or not

Comment: i can do this with firebase

Comment: You can create a report abuse from like [this](https://report-abuse-form-flutter.web.app/#/). In the form, you can collect their id, reason, etc. Then, save that information in database you know (firestore etc).